# Not able to Update wordpress to 4.0

Tags: updates

I have a Wordpress 3.7 installation on AWS and I am not able to upgrade it to 4.0.

As soon as I try to auto update it, the redirect link goes to http://domain.com/wordpress/update-core.php

But it times out and redirects to the login page. if I try to login again, I am not able to do so.

If I login in a new tab, with link http://domain.com/wp-login.php, I am able to login.
Searching google is also not helping.

Comment: Why don't you manually update it. Download no-content WordPress from here `https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-4.0-no-content.zip` and replace old files with downloaded. Make sure you keep backup of old files and database.

Comment: @Roberthue I am Already doing it manually. thanks for your reply